# replace _ with 2 values T and A

Tags: r, dplyr, replace

I am doing manipulation of appointment key originally with pipes || in R.
Now replaced || with underscore _ = 14198_16692_1 as an example
Now need to replace the first _ with T and the 2nd with A.
Wondering what your thoughts on dplyr or similar package to achieve like
14198T16692A1.

Comment: I am not able to type an answer at the the but stringr str_replace will replace the first instance of a pattern with the replacement.

 `my_newStr<-str_replace(str_replace(myStrVector,'_','T'),'_','A')` something along those lines.

Comment: @MichaelVine = great and got it > my_newStr<-str_replace(str_replace('14198_16692_1','_','T'),'_','A')
> my_newStr
[1] "14198T16692A1"

Comment: @MichaelVine i like your solution which is really simple but cannot flag as answer tick in SO facility here

Comment: The other answer is a more valid and correct answer. So please mark that as the answer

Comment: done.  How professional you are!  Appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take help of capture groups -

```
x <- '14198_16692_1'
sub('(\\w+)_(\\w+)_(.*)', '\\1T\\2A\\3', x)
#[1] "14198T16692A1"
```

To apply this to whole column in a dataframe replace `x` with `df$col` where `df` is the dataframe name and `col` is the column name.

Comment: sorry, what is w+ for?

Comment: `\\w+` stands for one word. So in `'14198_16692_1'` the first `\\w+` is `14198` and the second `\\w+` is `16692`.

Comment: that's great and helpful